# how to limit file size when it's working?

Tags: linux, multicast

I have a problem.
I need convert multicast source using opencaster.
I receive multicast and write to file input.ts, then i send input.ts to other multicast:
`tsudpreceive 239.1.1.1 50000 > input.ts &
tsudpsend input.ts 224.5.5.5 5000 3000000 &`
but input.ts size have grown.
I have no idea to stop it.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making input.ts an ordinary file, create it by using "mkfifo input.ts"